# Error validating access token in Hello.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, hello.js

I am using Hello.js for social login in my website . I am using a standard code that has been provided in the documentation [**HERE**](http://adodson.com/hello.js/#quick-start).

my code looks something like this

```
<script>
    //user;
    hello.on('auth.login', function (auth) {
        // call user information, for the given network
        hello(auth.network).api('/me').then(function (r) {
            // Inject it into the container
            //alert(r.name);
            window.user = r.email;
            window.im_name = r.name;
            if (r.email) ajax1();

        });
    });

    hello.init({
        facebook: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        google: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5-q6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxeusercontent.com',
    }, {
        redirect_uri: 'http://wstation.yzx.com/',
        scope: 'email'

    });

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn-fb" onclick="hello( 'facebook' ).login()">Facebook</button>
<button class="btn-google" onclick="hello( 'google' ).login()">Google</button>
```

Every thing is working fine I am able to login through Facebook and then send the credentials to the server to sign in the user. But after the user sign in . The `Ajax1()` method is called again and again all the time.

I am trying to read through the Documentation but nothing is helping out

**UPDATE**

I changed the code into something like this

```
function connect(x){
hello(x).api("/me").then(function(r){
        window.user = r.email;
        window.im_name = r.name;
        if (r.email) ajax1();
}, function(e){
    alert("Whoops! " + e.error.message );
});
}
```

and **HTML**

```
<button class="btn-fb" onclick="connect('facebook')">Facebook</button>
<button class="btn-google" onclick="connect('google')">Google</button>
```

Now I am getting error

```
Whoops! Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error.
```

as an alert

Please help me if any one had same problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it worked Hopefully it helps some one else having the same problem

```
<script>

function connect(x){
hello(x).login().then(function(r){
    hello(r.network).api('/me').then(function(r){
        alert('Login');
        window.user = r.email;
        window.im_name = r.name;
        if (r.email) ajax1();
}, function(e){
    alert("Whoops! " + e.error.message );
});
});

}
hello.init({
    facebook: '2xxxxxxxxxxx4',
    google: '3xxxxxxxxx5-qxxxxxxxxxxxxx6k1nunigepmsd3.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    twitter: 'Yxxxxxxxxxxxw'
}, {
    redirect_uri: 'http://wstation.inmotico.com/',
    scope: 'email'

});


</script>
```

Thanks & Regards